# Remove item of list in Applescript

Tags: list, applescript

Is there a way to remove a specific item from a list in Applescript?

So something like this:

```applescript
set theList to {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
remove item 3 of theList
log theList

--Should log: (*1, 2, 4, 5*)
```

Comment: Per the ASLG, you cannot: "For a list object, you cannot remove items…" from [Applescript and Objects](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/conceptual/ASLR_fundamentals.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH218-SW7). You can do what matt suggests in his answer though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no higher level function like *removeItemAtIndex* in AppleScript.

Writing such a function is quite cumbersome because unlike the other programming/script languages AppleScript indices start at 1.

For example

```
on removeItem from theList at theIndex
    if theIndex > (count theList) or theIndex is 0 then return theList
    if theIndex = 1 then
        return items 2 thru -1 of theList
    else if theIndex is (count theList) then
        return items 1 thru -2 of theList
    else
        tell theList to return items 1 thru (theIndex - 1) & items (theIndex + 1) thru -1
    end if
end removeItem
```

It's a bit easier with the help of the Foundation Framework (keeping the 1-based indices)

```
use AppleScript version "2.5"
use framework "Foundation"

on removeItem from theList at theIndex
    if theIndex > (count theList) or theIndex is 0 then return theList
    set mutableArray to current application's NSMutableArray's arrayWithArray:theList
    mutableArray's removeObjectAtIndex:(theIndex - 1)
    return mutableArray as list
end removeItem
```

Comment: I tried replicating the javascript-`array.splice` method like this:`on splice(theStart, theLength, theList)
 return items 1 thru (theStart - 1) of theList & items (theStart + theLength) thru (count of theList) of theList
end splice` It isn't beautiful but it works.

Comment: You get an error if you are going to remove the first item. And you should perform the index checks, too.

Answer (score 2):

There is no magic way. You just make a list consisting of the items you want.  For example

```
set theList to (items 1 thru 2 of theList & items 4 thru -1 of theList)
```

Answer (score 0):

Nobody forces anyone to write a handler in a cumbersome form. If we remove all these ELSEs, and take into account the fact that an error should normally be thrown when going out of the list.

```
on removeItemAtIndex:anIndex fromList:aList
    if anIndex = 1 then return rest of aList
    if anIndex = (count aList) then return items 1 thru -2 of aList
    tell aList to items 1 thru (anIndex - 1) & items (anIndex + 1) thru -1
end removeItemAtIndex:fromList:

set theList to {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
my removeItemAtIndex:3 fromList:theList
```

Also, if the list contains elements of the same AppleScript class, it is possible to obtain an additional simplification:

```
set theList to {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
set item 3 of theList to missing value
return integers of theList
```

or,

```
set theList to {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5"}
set item 3 of theList to missing value
set theList to text of theList
```

Comment: *cumbersome* means the necessity  to check the first and last index. Removing the `else` expressions is pure syntactic sugar.