# How can you detect NaN in Applescript?

Tags: applescript, nan

So I have a python script that does some math that I call via `do shell script` like this:

```applescript
return do shell script "/usr/local/bin/python3.9 /path/to/my/file.py"
(*Python file returns something like this:
...
25.537989061650084
27.01428839325525
nan
nan
23.678689253368486
nan
35.00336192227798
37.77710795005522
37.70807585046893
38.02099024474269
37.2270982297317
36.90066402440177
37.00379510935199
...
*)
```

The `NaN`'s in there are no problem, however, I want to filter them out. I have a [function that removes items from lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68963070/remove-item-of-list-in-applescript) and as soon as a `nan` appears, I want to filter it out.

I tried multiple methods:

```applescript
set theParagraphs to paragraphs of (do shell script "/usr/local/bin/python3.9 /path/to/my/file.py")
repeat with currentItem in theParagraphs
    try
        set currentItem to currentItem as number --produces no error
        set currentItem to currentItem + 0 --produces no error
    on error
        --remove item from list here
    end try
    
    if currentItem is equal to "nan" then -- False 
        --remove item from list here
    end if
    
    if currentItem is not equal to currentItem then --False
        --remove item from list here
    end if
end repeat
```

Is there any easy way to either get it to produce an error or compare it to anything?

Comment: `currentItem` is actually a _reference_ to an item in the list - it needs to be dereferenced or coerced to text for the comparison, e.g. `if (currentItem as text) is equal to "nan" then`

Comment: @red_menace tried it, doesn't work.

Comment: @gurkensaas As a tip for the future, avoid simply saying something _“doesn’t work”_ because that is only useful if you describe in what way something didn’t work, together with what actually happens instead.  Besides preventing further diagnosis of the problem, it also dismisses a suggestion that many times can turn out to be a perfectly good suggestion that fails only because of something at the user’s end. @red_menace’s suggestion in this case was correct, and would work. Either your method for removing list items is the issue or you’ve put everything inside a `try` block.

Answer (score 2):

```
set my text item delimiters to {["NaN\n"], "\nNaN"}
set sh to "/usr/local/bin/python3.9 /path/to/my/file.py"
set py to (do shell script sh)'s text items as text
set R to every paragraph of py
```

If you want them as numbers rather than numerical strings, the most conventional way would be to iterate and coerce:

```
repeat with x in a reference to R
    tell x to set its contents ¬
        to the contents as real
end repeat
```

Comment: Seriously, thank you for your answer, however, I already "moved on" and going back to introducing a buggy state of my code would be a bit much, I will still upvote your answer for the effort though.

Comment: You forgot to upvote, but I appreciate the thought.  I didn’t necessarily contribute the answer only for your benefit, so while you may have moved on, these questions and answers remain a resource for other people to read in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up checking it in the Python Script using:

```py
if str(result) != "nan":
    print(result)
```

Comment: Not sure why testing the string in Python would be different than in AppleScript (unless the repeat loop variable was not getting dereferenced), but that is a better place for the test, anyway.

Comment: @red_menace Maybe it was because I didn't put an `as string` after the python call but in the end, I think both would have worked. Should I delete the question?